# Visual glitch on activity transition

Tags: android, android-activity, transition, visual-glitch

I'm working on an application using ABS.
And when I use this custom activity animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="1400"/>
</set>
```

Either with *overridePendingTransition* or *getWindow().setWindowAnimations()*

I see a with space on the top on the activity while it's sliding, where the notifications bar would be.

And this glitch doesn't occur on ICS, I don't now if it's related to ABS, but do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update this...
**android:toYDelta="0%p"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" android:duration="1400"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention something about the way you defined the transition. Starting on Android 8.0, the translation animation has a small glitch if you define percentages as "0%p". Instead, define them as "0%".